# How to add a fragment over a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to create a functionality.. like;

There will be a fragment in the behind a fragment; the fragment in the front will be transparent.

1. **Fragment_front** in the front will be static ie the fragment will either be minimized to a title or it will show its contents.
2. **Fragment_back** will be behind the fragment_front, when the user slides down, it will come beneath fragment_front.

Any ideas on how can I develop such thing?? Need help!! Have been stuck on this one since 2 weeks! I have tried all possible things(that I can think of) still nothing seems to work.

Comment: @SukhwantSinghGrewal There are many apps in the market with such cosmetic. Dont say "I dont think this is possible" & downvote. Thats rude!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, You need play music like slide up view.

> [image]

If so, putting fragment back to back wouldn't be a right approach, and fragment doesn't provide any slide functionality . You might want to use [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) library.

Comment: Yes Abhishek. I need a functionality just like that. I will try it. Thanks!